# Does John 17:23 teach that God loves the world or believers in the same way He loves Jesus?

Tags: john, prayer

> I in them and you in me—so that they may be brought to complete unity. Then the world will know that you sent me and have loved them even as you have loved me.

John 17:23 says that the Father loves "them" even as He loved Christ. Is the "them" Jesus is referring to "the world" or those who believe in Jesus? The sentence is phrased in such a way that I can see both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The whole chapter of John 17 is Jesus' prayers.

John 17:1-5 is a prayer for Himself and His work. John 17:6-19 is a prayer for those the Father gave Jesus, His disciples. John 17:20-26 is a prayer for those who believe in Him.

John 17:20 NIV

> My prayer is not for them (Jesus' disciples) alone. **I pray also for those who will believe in me through their message**

Therefore, Jesus is very specific praying for those who believe in Him, not to the world. In Gospel, the world is usually an synonym to wicked.

John 15:19 NIV

> If you belonged to the world, it would love you as its own. As it is, you do not belong to the world, but I have chosen you out of the world. That is why the world hates you.

John 17:14 NIV

> I have given them your word and the world has hated them, for they are not of the world any more than I am of the world.

So for those belonged to the world, they do not believe in Jesus. Those believe in Jesus, the world will hate them. **Jesus did not pray for the world.**

Comment: I disagree that Jesus didn't pray for the world. He prayed so that "the world would believe that You have sent me."

Comment: @Jesus_is_Lord777 - The full context is “My prayer is not for them alone. I pray also for 'those who will believe in me' through their message, 'that all of them may be one', Father, just as you are in me and I am in you. May they also be in us so that the world may believe that you have sent me. (John 17:20-21 NIV). Jesus prayed for His believers that from them, the world (unbelievers) may believe in Jesus. This is different to praying for the world, for the unbelievers will not turn without hearing the Gospel. So Jesus prayed for the believers 
to shine their light to the world.

Comment: I see what you mean! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks, “John 17:23 says that the Father loves 'them' even as He loved Christ. Is the 'them' Jesus is referring to 'the world' or those who believe in Jesus? The sentence is phrased in such a way that I can see both cases.” I would agree. There is ambiguity in this section of the passage, a passage that starts out by making rather clear distinctions between the world and those who are in the world, but not of the world (vv 13-16).

John 17:16 NKJ

> 16 They are not of the world, just as I am not of the world.

While it is relatively clear in the above verse who the “they” are, that clarity begins to diminish around verse 20, where the “they” refers not only to Jesus' disciples but also those who “believe in Me through their word.”

> 20 “I do not pray for these alone, but also for those who will believe
> in Me through their word; 21 that they all may be one, as You, Father,
> are in Me, and I in You; that they also may be one in Us, that the
> world may believe that You sent Me.

By verse 23, it becomes harder to discern who it is that comprise the last “them” at the end, whether it references only the “they” at the start of the verse or whether it also includes those who comprise “the world.”

> 23 I in them, and You in Me; that they may be made perfect in one, and
> that the world may know that You have sent Me, and have loved them as
> You have loved Me.

The third person plural pronoun in this passage is like a net, one that begins small, referring to only Jesus’ first disciples (v6), but that widens further and further until it encompasses the world (v23). This, I believe, is Jesus’ model of how faith is meant to spread - from one person to another in an ever growing circle of believers.

Reflecting on this passage, I see God’s love as the unifying factor, transmitted to believers through Christ, and to others through those who believe in him (cf Jn 13:34, 15:12). In the end, the question becomes less about who it is that God loves than about who has come to know and receive the love that is from God.

> 26 And I have declared to them Your name, and will declare it, that
> the love with which You loved Me may be in them, and I in them.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be no doubt that:

> God is love (1 John 4:8, 16)

... and ...

> "God so loved the world that He gave ..." (John 3:16)

This dependable, abiding and constant agape-love is celebrated in 1 Cor 13.  It is others-focused so excludes all self-centeredness.  This love is the essence and very nature of God, the foundation of His being.

The best definition of agape love is, “God so loved … that He gave His son …” (John 3:16).  The “agape” love is the central most important characteristic, the very essence, of God (1 John 4:8, 16).  Love’s outward manifestation is grace.  It is God as love that defines God and all else about Him such as justice/righteousness tempered with kindness.

This principled love of God (1 John 4:8, 16) is to be imitated by all Christians (John 13:34, 35) and is motivated by God’s love for us (1 John 4:9, 10, 19-21, 2 Cor 5:14).

With God, there are no degrees of love, it is simply measureless, unbounded and unfailing.  Jesus Himself confirmed this twice in John 17:

> V23 - I in them and You in Me—that they may be perfectly united, so
> that the world may know that You sent Me **and have loved them just as
> You have loved Me**.
>
> V26 - And I have made Your name known to them and will continue to
> make it known, so that the love You have for **Me may be in them**, and I
> in them.”

John 17 is sometimes called by Christians, "Jesus High-Priestly Prayer".  As such it is a perfect record of Jesus and God's love for believers.

**Finally -**

As stated above, in John 17 Jesus' prayer consists of three sections:

- Jesus' prayer for Himself, V1-5
- Jesus' prayer for His disciples, V6-19
- Jesus' prayer for all believers

Jesus does not pray directly for "The world", BUT, Jesus does pray that His believers may be In Him and He in them so that the world will believe.  However, Jesus still said that God loved the world in other places such as John 3:16, Titus 2:14, Gal 1:4, Eph 5:2, Rom 5:5, 8, 8:35, 37, 39, Gal 2:20.

Comment: I thought Jesus was praying for the world when He prays "so that the world might believe..."

Comment: @Jesus_is_Lord777 - That is correct - Jesus prayed that the believers might represent Him correctly to the world  so that others might may believe